# Are refresh tokens necessary with reference tokens?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4, openid-connect

We have a Web API secured with IdentityServer4 using local API authentication. We are currently using both Reference Tokens and Refresh Tokens. Since we have the ability to revoke a reference token at any time is it even necessary for us to use refresh tokens? Couldn't we just set a long expiry for the reference token? Is there any security implications to this approach?

Comment: I don't know what a "reference" token means here, and you may wish to explain this.  Generally speaking, the purpose of refresh tokens is to avoid forcing the user to re-enter his credentials to keep the session going.  So, my guess is that yes it is necessary to use refresh tokens, if you want a smooth user experience.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen [Reference token](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html) is an IdentityServer4 feature.

Comment: Thanks @RuardvanElburg. In short a reference token is not a self contained token like a JWT and does not contain any claims. You use the reference token to get the claims from the identity server. JWTs usually cannot be revoked so generally you want to make them short lived and you will use a refresh token to get a new one when needed. A reference token in IdentityServer can be revoked so hence my question, do I even need the refresh token anymore?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html):

> When using reference tokens - IdentityServer will store the contents
>   of the token in a data store and will only issue a unique identifier
>   for this token back to the client. The API receiving this reference
>   must then open a back-channel communication to IdentityServer to
>   validate the token.

In other words, the client doesn't have to provide an access token to the api, only pass the reference.

This is a big difference between the JWT token and the reference token. The client sends the API the JWT token that has to be trusted by the API without consulting the provider, while the reference token forces the API to contact the provider, not having to rely on the client.

From the [Refresh Tokens documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html):

> Since access tokens have finite lifetimes, refresh tokens allow
>   requesting new access tokens without user interaction.

The question now is, can a reference token expire? Not from itself, as it contains no logic, unlike the JWT token. But there may be a server side setting that triggers some kind of expiration, or actually cause the reference to be revoked.

Either way, there is no use for a refresh token in this scenario. As you can't refresh the reference token. The reference token either exists or not (is invalid or was revoked).

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but I assume the AccessTokenLifetime setting on the client applies to both reference tokens and jwt's.

Comment: The stored information may expire, but that's not the concern of the client application. Please note that the reference token doesn't have to expire as it can be revoked, unlike a JWT that can't be revoked. Besides, the client has no way of checking the status (expiration) of the server side information. All it does is send the reference token along with the request to the resource.

Comment: So the answer to your question is no: refresh tokens aren't necessary with reference tokens as you can revoke the token  without having to set an expiration time.